# Не статический метод: можно ли обойти проблему (Strict Standards)?

Tags: скрипт, php

Всем доброго времени суток!

Устанавливаю PHP скрипт. Вот что выдает:

> `Strict Standards: Non-static method db_main::Quot() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/******/data/www/*****/****/core/moduleinterface.php on line 63`

Итак, очень много строчек - ошибки такого же типа (`Non-static method`). Что самое интересное, установка скрипта продолжается нормально, т.е выводятся формы, какие-то элементы и т.д.

- Можно ли в файле php.ini отключить `E_STRICT`? ошибки.
- Или же нужно переписывать код под стандарт?

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста.

Желательно бы, не как скрыть эти ошибки - а как именно исправить их. Потому что, я даже читал, static экономит время. Скрипт выполняется в 2 раза быстрее

Comment: Неужели никто не знает?
реально не могу поверить. Где все php программисты?
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

`E_STRICT` - это не столько ошибки, сколько советы по правильному кодированию, для предотвращения последующей несовместимости скрипта, и при уровне информирования `E_ALL`, `E_STRICT` - незадействован, он нужен только разработчику. Ставьте `E_ALL`, и забудьте за сообщение. А исправить в каждой ситуации посвоему. Нет единого ответа. Ошибку может вызвть не переданый аргумент функции в дочерном классе, который объявлен в родительском. Такие предупреждения есть почти в любом коде. Без этих ошибок может работать быстрее, но как правило время экономиться в поиске и выводе этих ошибок. Ставьте `E_ALL`, если Вы неразработчик и наслаждайтесь :)))

Answer (score 1):

Можно лишь отключить ВЫВОД ошибок. Но не сами ошибки.
Делается это так:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

записью в ини файле.

Или же установить пхп версией ниже, скажем 5.2.Х

Или же (самый идеальный вариант) скачать обновленную версию этого "скрипта"

Comment: Спасибо конечно большое, но по делу нового ничего не услышал.
Я все писал выше. Ошибки отключить конечно можно, но повлияет ли потом это на работу скрипта? И как правильно исправить.